# Can specutils be used for fitting of a spectrum

Tags: python

Mac Notebook OSX Yosemite 10.10.5 jupyter notebook, python 2.7
python spectutils is not working
The first code given in the instruction manual

```
import numpy as np
import astropy.units as u
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from specutils import Spectrum1D
flux = np.random.randn(200)*u.Jy
wavelength = np.arange(5100, 5300)*u.AA
spec1d = Spectrum1D(spectral_axis=wavelength, flux=flux)
ax = plt.subplots()[1]
ax.plot(spec1d.spectral_axis, spec1d.flux)
ax.set_xlabel("Dispersion")
ax.set_ylabel("Flux")
```

ends  with

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2e15c1951be1> in <module>()
      5 flux = np.random.randn(200)*u.Jy
      6 wavelength = np.arange(5100, 5300)*u.AA
----> 7 spec1d = Spectrum1D(spectral_axis=wavelength, flux=flux)
      8 ax = plt.subplots()[1]
      9 ax.plot(spec1d.spectral_axis, spec1d.flux)

TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (2 given)
```

what do I have to do to get it working?

Comment: You forgot to mention that you code is exactly comming from [this](https://specutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spectrum1d.html) example! this means your code has probably no problem as it worked on the authors machine. What's the version of the specutils?

Comment: the code is from https://specutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spectrum1d.html; my spectutils is version 2.13.0